# I got scammed because metamask didn't flag a scammers wallet address. Can they be held liable for this?

Tags: metamask, wallet-transfer, scam

I was scammed into sending ether to a wallet address, but apparently this was an ongoing scheme. I flagged the address on metamask, as I suspect many others had, since the scam had been running for days with the same address. Now, two days later I see no warning or flag for this address. Can metamask be held liable for not flagging it? I can see the transactions on this account are continuing, so many more are falling victim to it.

Comment: I think not, but could you somehow report that address on etherscan ? so other people don’t get scammed by it easily

Comment: I mean, you sent the transaction and not the Metamask so they cannot be liable for your own fault. As for flagging the address, it probably takes some time before it is included in the list.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on Metamask's [support page](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052511372),

> Unfortunately, transactions cannot be reversed, nor missing the funds restored. MetaMask is a non-custodial wallet, which means we cannot control access to user accounts, nor intervene and rescue your account or funds for you.

They do have a page on avoiding [common scams](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412217080091-Common-scams-and-how-to-avoid-them). You should [report the scam](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/5168786362779).